# Showing a specific input box based on select value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to javascript but I have tried to tie which input box is shown based on the select box option. I was wondering if someone could look at my tiny bit of code, and firstly tell me why it isn't working, and secondly tell me if there is a better way of achieving this.

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/MJGmg/2/

```
function applyselect()
{
    if (!$("#apply email:selected").length) {
    $("website").addClass("hidden");        
    }
    else {
    $("email").addClass("hidden");         
    }
}

$(function() {
  applyselect();
});
```

P.s I would quite like to keep it wrapped in a function.

Comment: you need to use onchange event of the select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the `change` event to the select.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#apply").change(function() {
        var selected = $(this).find(':selected').val(),
            elem = $("#"+selected);
        $("input").addClass('hidden');
        elem.removeClass('hidden');
    });
    $("#apply").trigger('change');
});
```

> Why `$("#apply").trigger('change');`?

Because it is needed to execute the function after the DOM is ready. Otherwise, you can remove that line and add `class="hidden"` to your `<input id="website">`(which, by default, is not the selected option when page loads).

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MJGmg/5/) of the code.

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MJGmg/10/)**

You should use `on` selector

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).on('change', '#apply',function() {
        var selected = $(this).find(':selected').val(),
            elem = $("#"+selected);
        $("input").addClass('hidden');
        elem.removeClass('hidden');
    });
    $("#apply").trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for stealing my code. Anyway, if you use `on`, wrapping the code inside `$(document).ready()` is not necessary, and in this specific case `on` is not necessary at all.

Comment: @LightStyle : your code is already better and I tried to make it best.

Comment: @LightStyle : `ready function` will help to add the handler.

Comment: In my opinion it is not "best", it is "superfluous"(and posted just to get some reputation).

Comment: Help to add the handler? What do you mean?

Comment: @LightStyle That's ok, you have the accepted answer anyway your answer not using delegation is better here

Comment: @LightStyle : Just tell me to remove this post and i will remove it immediately, if you don't like it.Because I only prefer to learn

Comment: @PKKG please don't delete it showing example of using delegation

Comment: @roasted: `on` is better? In this case, if I'm not wrong, is not necessary. @PKKG no, no need to delete, just, IMHO, it is not necessary(but maybe I'm wrong, I could have misunderstood how `on` works)

Comment: @LightStyle when i said <<your answer not using delegation is better >> i was talking about your answer

Comment: It's always better to use `on` especially in case of `Dynamic elements`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment :) @PKKG, I agree with that, but do you see a dynamic element?

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting the `#` to match the id of your element.

```
$("website").addClass("hidden"); 
   ^---- Here goes a #
```

Same for your other call `$("email").addClass("hidden");`

Comment: I put this here but still not working: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/MJGmg/3/